# Dataflow blocks when some parallel process does a heavy job

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, dataflow

I'm trying to understand  TPL Dataflow. 
I have two blocks inputBlock och nextBlock.

inputBlock using MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2.
I have this situation that it can take diffrent time to parallell jobs to finish. I do not want the flow of data stops due some parallell job takes long time to finish.
I simply want each parallell job take one item from the queue and process it and then pass it to next block.

I do never reach nextBlock when one of the parallel job in the first block "inputBlock" goes to sleep or do a heavy job.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static bool _sleep = true;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inputBlock = new TransformBlock<string, string>(
            x =>
            {
                if (_sleep)
                {
                    _sleep = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("First thread sleeping");
                    Thread.Sleep(5000000);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Second thread running");
                return x;
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2}); //1


        var nextBlock = new TransformBlock<string, string>(
            x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                return x;
            }); //2

        inputBlock.LinkTo(nextBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});


        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            input.Post(i.ToString());
        }

        input.Complete();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EnsureOrdered = false was the answer.

new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2, EnsureOrdered = false});